# Array swapping in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to swap elements between two array starting from a particular array index value keeping other values prior to the array index intact.

```
import numpy as np
r = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
p = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])

t = []
for i in range(len(r)):
    for j in range(len(p)):
        if i >= 3 and j >= 3:
            t.append(p[j])
            p[j] = r[i]
            for k in t:
                r[i] = k
```

The above code does the task but the values are in reverse order.
The value that I want in array `p` after swapping is:

```
[70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60]
```

and the value that i want in array r after swapping is:

```
[10, 20, 30, 100, 110, 120]
```

But in array `p` I am getting:

```
[70, 80, 90, 60, 50, 40]
```

and in array `r` I am getting:

```
[10, 20, 30, 120, 110, 100]
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: i suspect the reverse has to do with how you accumulate temporary values in `t`.  You need to print values during each iteration to track that down.  But as the answers show you don't need to use iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same without looping:

```
r = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
p = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])

i = 3
temp = p[i:].copy()
p[i:] = r[i:]
r[i:] = temp
```

Now:

```
>>> p
array([70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60])
>>> r
array([ 10,  20,  30, 100, 110, 120])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
r = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
p = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])

for i in range(len(r)):
    if (i>=3):
        p[i],r[i] = r[i],p[i]
```

Above code will do the work for you. You don't need to run two for loop and t array if I understand your problem right. All you want is to swap at some indexes. You can just swap at those indexes as above no need of a temporary array t.

Comment: Thanks. The above code works well. But, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: 1) You don't need two loops.
2) You don't need a temporary array t. You only need current index value i.e `t=p[i]`
3) What exactly is the last for loop doing? It is same as doing r[i]=t[-1]. 
4) Print array t to see what it stores. You will see it stores values in random order (undesired order)

Comment: Why not `range(3,len(r)` and skip the if test?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Saves some iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a slice of one array on to the other:

```
In [113]: r = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
     ...: p = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])
     ...: 
In [114]: t = p.copy()
In [115]: t[3:]=r[3:]
In [116]: t
Out[116]: array([70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60])
```

You could also join slices:

```
In [117]: np.concatenate((p[:3], r[3:]))
Out[117]: array([70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60])
```

Those answers create a new array.  I think that's clearer than doing an inplace swap.  But here's how I'd do the swap

```
In [128]: temp = r[3:].copy()
In [129]: r[3:]=p[3:]
In [130]: p[3:]=temp
In [131]: r
Out[131]: array([ 10,  20,  30, 100, 110, 120])
In [132]: p
Out[132]: array([70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60])
```

I use `copy` in `temp` because otherwise a slice produces a `view`, which will get modified in the next copy.  That issue has come up recently when swapping rows of a 2d array.

With lists the swapping is easier - because `r[3:]` makes a copy.

```
In [139]: r=r.tolist()
In [140]: p=p.tolist()
In [141]: temp = r[3:]
In [142]: r[3:], p[3:] = p[3:], r[3:]
In [143]: r
Out[143]: [10, 20, 30, 100, 110, 120]
In [144]: p
Out[144]: [70, 80, 90, 40, 50, 60]
```